# Is Spring-cloud-stream application without spring-boot possible?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to write an application using spring-cloud-stream rabbitmq but without using spring-boot. When I do `gradle dependencies` I see that the cloud-stream is dependent on spring boot modules. Is it possible to use spring-cloud-stream without spring-boot? Can someone point me to any example?

```
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream: -> 1.0.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0 -> 2.4.4
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.4
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.0.15 -> 7.0.57
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.0.15 -> 7.0.57
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.0.15 -> 7.0.57
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.0.15 -> 7.0.57
|    |    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.57
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.4 (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final
|    |    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.2.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.projectreactor:reactor-core:1.1.4.RELEASE -> 1.1.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- com.goldmansachs:gs-collections:5.1.0
|    |    |    |    \--- com.goldmansachs:gs-collections-api:5.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.lmax:disruptor:3.2.1
|    |    |    +--- io.gatling:jsr166e:1.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.8
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.1.RELEASE -> 1.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.4.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:3.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:1.3.0
|    |    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.6 -> 2.4.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.6.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.2.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit: -> 1.0.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:1.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:1.0.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-codec:1.0.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:3.0.3 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.6 -> 2.4.4
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.4.1.RELEASE -> 1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.4.2 -> 3.4.3
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:1.4.2.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:4.2.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.4.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.8
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.8
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.8
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.8
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.8
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.8
|    |         \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2
|    |              +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2
|    |              \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.8
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE -> 1.2.1.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:4.2.5.RELEASE -> 4.1.2.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.1.2.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:1.0.2.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok: -> 1.14.8
```

Answer (score 5):

No; Spring Cloud Stream utilizes a lot of Spring Boot features; it is required.