# How to use RabbitMQ in Maven test project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, rabbitmq

There is a test framework Maven project which uses the following Spring related libraries to run Cucumber tests, but it's NOT a Spring Boot project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There are also several Spring Boot apps microservices to handle connected hardware (mobile phones and Bluetooth devices), which use Cloud Stream RabbitMQ binder to communicate with each other:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Currently we send REST requests from our test automation Maven project to these Spring apps, but we're assuming it would be better to send messages instead.

I've tried to use Rabbit in test project in the same way it's used in Spring Boot projects, but looks like it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605418/is-spring-cloud-stream-application-without-spring-boot-possible).

1. **The first question is**: Is it possible to dynamically create channels and connection to the same Rabbit service other microservices are connected to?

I've also tried to convert our Maven project to Spring Boot, added Spring Cloud dependencies mentioned above and run Cucumber tests using **mvn test** command. I also added the following properties in my application.properties:

```
#Messaging system
spring.rabbitmq.host=127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

#Messaging channels
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.eurekaOutChannel.destination=eurekaChannel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.eurekaInChannel.destination=eurekaChannel
```

But as far as I can see in logs, rabbit binder and channels haven't been created automatically, only default errorChannel.

```
2021-03-31 14:04:44.199  INFO 31740 --- [           main] r.utilities.hooks.common.CucumberHooks   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-31 14:04:44.915  INFO 31740 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2021-03-31 14:04:44.926  INFO 31740 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2021-03-31 14:04:44.934  INFO 31740 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2021-03-31 14:04:44.981  INFO 31740 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-03-31 14:04:44.989  INFO 31740 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-03-31 14:04:45.522  INFO 31740 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-03-31 14:04:45.722  INFO 31740 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2021-03-31 14:04:45.724  INFO 31740 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'FarmTest.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-31 14:04:45.726  INFO 31740 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2021-03-31 14:04:45.737  INFO 31740 --- [           main] r.utilities.hooks.common.CucumberHooks   : Started CucumberHooks in 2.141 seconds (JVM running for 28.5)
```

At the same time when I run one of our Spring Boot microservices, rabbit binder and channels are created automatically:

```
2021-03-29 10:36:44.363  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.androidInChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:44.364  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.eurekaInChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:44.364  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.hiInChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:44.369  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2021-03-29 10:36:44.370  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:44.370  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2021-03-29 10:36:44.373  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: rabbit
2021-03-29 10:36:47.188  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Caching the binder: rabbit
2021-03-29 10:36:47.188  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: rabbit
2021-03-29 10:36:47.248  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [127.0.0.1:5672]
2021-03-29 10:36:47.310  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#1de13f34:0/SimpleConnection@2404abe2 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 63887]
2021-03-29 10:36:47.348  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.eurekaOutChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:47.350  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: rabbit
2021-03-29 10:36:47.517  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.hiOutChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:47.517  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: rabbit
2021-03-29 10:36:47.596  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'FarmCoreService.androidOutChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2021-03-29 10:36:47.597  INFO 21608 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: rabbit
```

2. **So the second question:** What's wrong with Maven test project configuration that it doesn't create rabbit binder and channels automatically?